# I Still Can't get my UI scroll view to scroll! iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll

So these are the steps I've done.

I dragged a scroll view to my view controller in story board, declared it in the .h file and wired it up.

In the scroll view, I have 6 labels with sizes, (320, 38), (262,72), (300, 38), (285,31), (285,31), (285,31).

The scroll View itself has width of 320 and height of 184.

In my viewDidLoad method, I added :

```
[self.scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1000)];
```

What am I doing wrong or missing to make this scroll view scrollable??

EDIT: The viewController is used with Auto-layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an opportunity for the view layout to complete before calling setContentSize. Move [self.scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1000)]; to viewDidLayoutSubviews or viewDidAppear.

Comment: THANK YOU. this is exactly what the problem was!